# LookAt while Hinge Jointed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I do not understand, why jointed object can't look at target.

Example: 2 boxes with hinge joint (anchor is at the touching place) and a target object. When I say A-box to lookAt target, I think it will just turn on X-axis. But both of the boxes start to shake. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a moment to reflect on what a call to `LookAt` is trying to do.

It's rotating the transform *while ignoring physics*.

That's bound to create problems, since you're not rotating the whole system, you're moving one part of it. Your rotation with `LookAt` is "fighting" with the adjustments the physics system is trying to make.

To solve that conflict you can do one of the following:

- Rotate the entire system (both cubes). This will involve putting them all under one transform, and having that transform rotate.
- Use a physics-based approach. It won't be too hard, but won't be as simple as a function call. You'll probably need a simple PID controller such as the one outlined in [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/rigidbody-lookat-torque.146625/).